# Is something wrong in this Spell checking using jquery

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, spell-checking

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // check the spelling on a textarea
        $("#check-textarea").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(".loading").show();
            $("#text-content")
            .spellChecker({
                lang: "en",
                engine: "google",
                suggestBoxPosition: "above"
            })
            .spellChecker('check', function (result) {

                // spell checker has finished checking words
                $(".loading").hide();

                // if result is true then there are no badly spelt words
                if (result) {
                    alert('There are no incorrectly spelt words.');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I am getting Error Message Object Does not support this property or method..

I used this link..

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/source/browse/#svn/trunk/css

Comment: This is unanswerable unless you point out which line the error occurs in

Comment: Hello Pekka, SOrry for that its showing me the Error in..  $("#text-content")
            .spellChecker({
                lang: "en",
                engine: "google",
                suggestBoxPosition: "above"
            })

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the incorrect source.

You should try ==> http://jquery-spellchecker.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.spellchecker.min.js

Not the CSS which you have listed ( http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/source/browse/#svn/trunk/css )

Also, as Jakub pointed out it's a lower case c in spellchecker

Check out the **[example page.](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-spellchecker/source/browse/trunk/example.html)**

Comment: Also I think spellchecker is spelled with lowercase c.

Comment: Yes I made those changes but still I am getting the Same Exception Object doesnot support this property or Method..